# Visual Studio Code: Remote Workspace reopen after close

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am trying to figure out if its possible to have vscode reopen my remotely saved workspace on open of the program automatically.

Additional info:

- I have the settings for a normal reopen on (restoreWindow).
- I see the workspace on my Open > Recents, but I want to automate this part

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly after a couple times opening and closing (didn't really pay attention to it, after two hours I noticed), it opens the workspace on its own. I was reopening it manually from Recents in the meantime.

It would be great to know where is this info stored in vscode to debug it manually.